# how to Plot CDF of interarrival time in python

Tags: python, plot, cdf

I want to plot a cdf for the interarrivale times I got, here is the dataset:

```
301.195365
300.574688
301.236683
0
0
298.485142
270.404616
270.404619
0
0
0
0
0
0
270.357415
270.357394
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
...
```

I have tried many suggestion that I found in other topics but it didn't work for me, here they are:

```
import scikits.statsmodels as sm
<....>
itr = getColumn("data.csv",0)
ecdf = sm.tools.ECDF(itr)
ax1.plot(itr, ecdf, 'rx')
```

The other one is:

```
import scipy.stats as stats
<....>
cdf = stats.binom.cdf
ax1.plot(itr, cdf(itr), 'rx')
```

I could use some of your help and explanation cause i don't get exactly how th cdf works so I can apply it on my data..

**Thanks**

Comment: To make your question more practical, you might edit your question to include the source code of one of the suggestions you initially thought was good but did not work for you.

Comment: oh yess sure! I was intended to do but i forgot x)

Comment: Are the zeros really zero inter-arrival times? If so the data come in batches, with some batches having just 1 item.  Do you want the CDF of all of the data, which will have a big step at dt=0, due to the batches,  or the CDF between batches, which ignores the fact that you have multiple items arriving at specific instants?